# Recursive partial functions in Coq

Tags: recursion, coq

I would like to know which is the best way to define a partial recursive function in Coq.

Suppose that I want to define a function that returns the maximum element of a list of natural numbers. However, we want this function to be defined only for non-empty lists.

I've been trying the following:

```
Fixpoint MaxValueList (l : list nat | l <> []) : nat :=
match l with
|[n] => n
|n::l' => (max n (MaxValueList l'))
end.
```

However, this is not going to work since `::` is a constructor for list and not for `{l : list nat | l <> []}`.

My other attempt was using `option`. In this case I tried the following:

```
Fixpoint MaxValueList (l : list nat | l <> []) : option nat :=
match l with
|[] => None
|[n] => n
|n::l' => (max n (MaxValueList l'))
end.
```

This did not work either since `max : nat -> nat -> nat` and `MaxValueList l' : option nat`.

Comment: Personally, I would favor Arthur's choice of max with a neutral element. One comment thou, the type `T = {l : list nat | l <> []}` is definitively speaking trouble, why? Because given two lists `l1 l2 : T` in order to prove their equality you must prove that the `l <> []` proofs are equal too, which is usually very hard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution to your problem:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition MaxValueListAux (n : nat) (l : list nat) : nat :=
  fold_left max l n.

Definition MaxValueListNE (l : list nat) : l <> [] -> nat :=
  match l with
  | []      => fun H => match H eq_refl with end
  | n :: l' => fun _ => MaxValueListAux n l'
  end.
```

Here, I've split the original `MaxValueList` into two parts: a `MaxValueListAux` function that computes the greatest element of a list given a default value, and `MaxValueListNE`, which is a wrapper to the first function and takes a proof argument. This second function merely discharges the impossible case and calls the first one with the appropriate arguments; I'll explain how exactly this works shortly. Because of this split, we don't run into the issue of constructing a proof argument in the nonempty branch of `MaxValueListNE`; the only proof work that we have to do is to get rid of the empty case.

Notice that the second function is written in a weird way: instead of declaring `l <> []` as another argument to `MaxValueListNE`, I've put it in the return type of that function. This is because of the way dependent pattern matching works in Coq; roughly speaking, whenever you need to combine information that you obtain on a `match` (such as the fact that the `l` is empty on the `[]` branch) with information that comes from "outside" the match (such as the proof of `l <> []`), you need to make your `match` statement return a function. This leads to a trick that Adam Chlipala calls the *convoy pattern*, which you can learn more about [here](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html). Putting that argument as part of the return type allows Coq to infer type annotations that are required by the `match` statement.

So, how exactly does `MaxValueListNE` work? To understand this, we must talk a little bit about how dependent pattern matching works in Coq. As I mentioned earlier, we wrote this function in this particular way so that Coq could infer some missing type annotations. But we can add those by hand as well:

```
Definition MaxValueListNE (l : list nat) : l <> [] -> nat :=
  match l return l <> [] -> nat with
  | []      => fun (H : [] <> [])      => match H eq_refl with end
  | n :: l' => fun (_ : n :: l' <> []) => MaxValueListAux n l'
  end.
```

When Coq reads this definition, it tries to type check the function, and, in particular, make sure that every branch of the `match` returns an element of the type it promises to return. But when doing so, it is allowed to replace every occurrence of the discriminee (in this case, `l`) by whatever value corresponds to that branch. In the first branch above, this means replacing `l` by `[]`, which in turn implies that the returned function takes an argument of type `[] <> []`. Recall that in Coq, `[] <> []` is the same thing as `[] = [] -> False`. Since `False` has no constructors, we can get rid of that contradictory branch by pattern-matching on `H eq_refl`, where `eq_refl` is the only constructor of the equality type, and is taken to have type `[] = []` in that particular case.

Now, it is worth noting that adding more type information is not necessarily good. In the case of your function, I prefer to omit the proof argument and write simply `Definition MaxValueList l := fold_left max l 0`. Note that 0 is a neutral element for `max`, thus it makes sense to return that value on the empty case. It allows us for instance to prove a result like

```
forall l1 l2, MaxValueList (l1 ++ l2) = max (MaxValueList l1) (MaxValueList l2)
```

Of course, this doesn't work for every case: if we replaced `max` by `min`, the above theorem wouldn't hold anymore. Still, I think it would still be easier to program with and reason about a `MinValueList` function that works for arbitrary lists: if some result about that function only works for nonempty elements, we can add those hypotheses to our theorem:

```
forall l1 l2, l1 <> [] -> 
  MinValueList (l1 ++ l2) = min (MinValueList l1) (MinValueList l2).
```

This is how people usually define division in Coq. Instead of having a partial function `div : forall (n1 n2 : nat), n2 <> 0 -> nat`, we write instead a total function `div : nat -> nat -> nat`, and prove *theorems* about that function assuming that its second argument is not zero.

Comment: Thank you! This was a nice answer and really clear. There is only one line that I don't get: `match H eq_refl with end`. I guess that the idea is that `H eq_refl` does not have any constructor so you don't need branching. So, `H : l <> []` but, what is exactly doing `eq_refl `? Maybe this is a really noob question.

Comment: I made an edit, trying to explain what eq_refl is doing there.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use `refine` tactic to construct functions using a theorem proving like style.

Whenever I need to construct terms with proofs (like your function) I prefer to use definitions and refine tactic, since it provides a more clear and easy way to automate proofs about propositions.

Below is a similar function that I have defined in a simple formalisation. You can modify it easily to enforce the non-empty list input requirement. The idea is to use refine tactic to provide the structure of the function and the proof terms for function properties are marked with holes "_" and latter filled with tactics.

```
Definition max_list : forall (l : list nat), {n | forall n', In n' l -> n > n'}.
  refine (fix max_list (l : list nat) : {n | forall n', In n' l -> n > n'} :=
        match l with
          | nil => exist _ 0 _
          | x :: l' =>
            match max_list l' with
              exist x' _ =>
                match le_gt_dec x x' with
                  | left _ => exist _ (S x') _
                  | right _ => exist _ (S x) _
                end
            end
        end) ; clear max_list  ; simpl in * ; intuition ;
               try (match goal with
                      | [H : context[In _ _ -> _],
                         H1 : In _ _ |- _] => apply H in H1 ; try omega
                    end).
Defined.
```

There are the so called [Program](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual027.html) functionality that eases writing functions with dependent types.  Maybe is worth checking it. My experience is that it generate some complicated hypothesis and, because of it, I prefer to use `refine`.

Answer (score 0):

The convoy pattern is a must to understand, but some of its reasoning can be avoided by using `Program`. `Program` also lets you write more normal looking programs.  I haven't really used it so I'll take this chance to try it.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.
Require Import Coq.Program.Wf.
```

From false you can derive a value of any type that you need.  Useful in impossible branches in a match statement.

```
Definition IMPOSSIBLE {T} (f:False):T := match f with end.

Program Fixpoint maxval (l:list nat) (H:l<>nil) {measure (length l)} : nat :=
  match l with
    | []       => IMPOSSIBLE _
    | [a]      => a
    | a::b::l' => max a (maxval (b::l') _)
  end.
```

EDIT: As `eponier` points out, if we include `Require Import Arith.`  before we define maxval, we will be done here.  Otherwise we will have to prove the remaining obligations, like this:  (END EDIT)

```
Next Obligation.
```

Now we only have to prove that the recursion terminates.  The goal is

```
============================
 well_founded
   (MR lt (fun recarg : {l : list nat & l <> []} => length (projT1 recarg)))
```

EDIT: `eponier` points out that this is easily proved by `apply measure_wf, PeanoNat.Nat.lt_wf_0.`

Comment: I am not very familiar either with `Program`, but I have found two ways. Manually `apply measure_wf` reduces the goal to `well_founded lt` which is proved for example by `PeanoNat.Nat.lt_wf_0`. Otherwise `Require Import Arith` before `Next Obligation` allows to write `Next Obligation. Defined` directly. If `Require Import Arith` is added before `Program Fixpoint`, it is even defined immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to read about `Program`. I know about it, but I did not go into detail.